# ModalDrawer Jetpack Compose - DrawerContent vs Content?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement ModalDrawer with Jetpack Compose. Now I'm using ModalDrawer composable function which requires two main parameters: DrawerContent and Content. This is what kind of result I get when I pass an empty content parameter and few elements inside a DrawerContent parameter. I get those two drawers, instead of one. It's really confusing.

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "Home") }
        )
    },
    drawerContent = {
        val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Open)
        ModalDrawer(
            drawerState = drawerState,
            drawerContent = { MyDrawerContent() },
            content = { }
        )
    },
    drawerContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
    content = {}
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Better to use or only `ModalDrawer` without scaffold or `Scaffold` with drawer content
because ModalDrawer already have drawerContent parameter so here is showing two drawers because of two drawer contents (nested).

```
Scaffold(
    drawerContent = {
        Text("Drawer title", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        Divider()
        // Drawer items
    }
) {
    // Screen content
}
```

OR

```
ModalDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            Column {
                Text("Text in Drawer")
                Button(onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.close()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Close Drawer")
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            Column {
                Text("Text in Bodycontext")
                Button(onClick = {

                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.open()
                    }

                }) {
                    Text("Click to open")
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks!